# Problemas con una libreria

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Hola amigos y amigas del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, tengo un pequeño problema al importar la siguiente librería:

```
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

el cual me arroja el siguiente error, que se ve en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer es cargar los datos de una tabla en un spinner, de una base de datos creada en mysql, para que el usuario pueda escoger un producto en particular, como soy nuevo en estas lides y aprendiendo cada día, me encontré con este problema y no se como solucionarlo, por lo que favor de ayudarme y desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

antes que nada el código no debe ir en imagen.
Ahora, el problema claramente es que las versiones de AndroidStudio actuales ya no usan `compile`, ahora se utiliza `implementation`. Según lo que veo, tu problema surge al implementar una librería, lo cual estás haciendo de manera incorrecta. He buscado esa librería y la encontré, este es su [Link](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/) a su página y este a [Link](https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http) a su repositorio en `GitHub`, observa que en **GitHub** se aclara el cómo implementar de manera correcta:

```
dependencies {
  //demases dependencias
  implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.11' //es con esta línea con la que debes implementar la librería
}
```

Debes observar también que debes añadir al repositorio `maven`:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `compile` no se reconoce y esa es la razón por la cual tu archivo build.gradle no puede sincronizarse con tu proyecto, debes usar `implementation`

```
//compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

---

`compile` es obsoleto hasta el Gradle 4.2 que ya no se usa actualmente en las nuevas versiones de Android Studio.
Ahora debes usar `implementation` :

> **implementation** : Gradle agrega la dependencia a la ruta de clase de
> la compilación y la empaqueta en el resultado de la compilación. Sin
> embargo, cuando tu módulo configura una dependencia implementation, se
> le informa a Gradle que no quieres que el módulo filtre la dependencia
> a otros módulos en el momento de la compilación. Es decir, la
> dependencia estará disponible para otros módulos solo durante el
> tiempo de ejecución.

Revisa
[**Cómo agregar dependencias de compilación**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, estuve leyendo el enlace el cual lo explica muy bien, se te agradece nuevamente